# Creating celery pipeline with tasks, that run only when some number of items in previous task are stacked

Tags: python, celery

I'm trying to create some kind of pipeline for my application. I have a problem - main target of application is to read video, take every N-th shot of video, and put it in the pipeline. Inside the pipeline there is 5 different tasks, for example:

```
1. Crop image
2. Store image in the array. if array length = IMAGES_NEEDED_FOR_TASK3, launch task 3
3. Apply some transforms to image, make one big image from IMAGES_NEEDED_FOR_TASK3,.
4. Stack transformed images in the array. if array length = IMAGES_NEEDED_FOR_TASK5, launch task 5
5. Write info about income images from task 4 to database
```

I struggle with implementations of task 2 and 4, because they have conditions. If they wouldn't have conditions, I would just use chain method. I thought about calling task 3 from task 2 (I thought to create a different queue for every task), but I read that this is considered as bad practice. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very difficult to express this in terms of the Celery workflow (if that is what you are struggling with), so I suggest you write the task 4 so it simply queues task #5 when the stack has IMAGES_NEEDED_FOR_TASK5 images (simply by calling app.send_task() or app.apply_async()).

Same goes for the task #2. You are fine as long as you do not need to deal with the result of tasks 3 and 5, in which case the logic becomes more complicated. It would be really nice if Celery has a primitive that could make it easier to express cases like this.

If you still insist on using the Celery workflow, then you should perhaps rethink the logic, and take advantage of the [Chunk primitive](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chunks). In this case your task #2 would `add.chunks()`. Same goes for the task #5.

Comment: Thanks, I made little POC (without chunks, just not waiting the results), and seems to work, so I mark it as the answer. Also, if you have some tools in mind, that would be suitable for such a task (or some approaches), I will be more than grateful for recommendations =). I was actually considering wrap each component in a separate service, and connect them with message broker, but for now it seems like an overcomplication (as this application should not be available 24/7 and will be used from time to time